# Inserting XY POINT (EPSG 4326) fails in sqlite3 shell

Tags: spatialite, sqlite

I'm working for the first time with spatial databases, using SpatiaLite. I'm working with Kotlin (Xerial's driver for JDBC) and it seems to work just fine. But I'm wondering why I am getting errors trying the same code in the `sqlite3` shell.

Here's an MRE, SQLite version 3.42.0 and SpatiaLite 5.1.0, x86_64, Linux:

```sql
sqlite> SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite');

sqlite> SELECT InitSpatialMetaData(1);
1
sqlite> CREATE TABLE message(content TEXT);
sqlite> SELECT AddGeometryColumn('message', 'coordinates', 4326, 'POINT', 'XY');
1
sqlite> INSERT INTO message(content, coordinates) VALUES ('hello!', GeomFromText('POINT(1.1 1.1)', 4326));
Parse error: unsafe use of GeometryConstraints()
```

Yet the point seems to be valid:

```
sqlite> SELECT ST_IsValid(GeomFromText('POINT(1.1 1.1)', 4326));
1
```

Why does this happen? I'm not entirely sure if that's my fault or not...

Comment: For debugging see https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.1.0.html and try what `CountUnsafeTriggers()`returns. Try then with "the environment variable SPATIALITE_SECURITY=relaxed". It should not be needed but try anyway.

Comment: @user30184 `CountUnsafeTriggers()` returns 0 either way.

Comment: I get the same behavior than you with SpatiaLite 5.1 Windows binaries. With spatialite.exe the insert succeeds, but with sqlite3 + mod_spatialite not. If I open the db after "AddGeometryColumn" with spatialite_gui app (older version, v. 5.1 does not exist yet), then the insert succeeds. Odd. Write mail to https://groups.google.com/g/spatialite-users and ask what is going on. The author of SpatiaLite does not follow this forum.

Comment: Try to add a primary key to the table `CREATE TABLE message (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, content TEXT);`

Comment: Works for me with no `Parse error: unsafe use of GeometryConstraints()` using SQLite version 3.37.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issues comes from the PRAGMA setting "trusted_schema"
https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_trusted_schema

> **PRAGMA trusted_schema;**
>
> **PRAGMA trusted_schema = boolean;**
>
> The trusted_schema setting is a per-connection boolean that determines
> whether or not SQL functions and virtual tables that have not been
> security audited are allowed to be run by views, triggers, or in
> expressions of the schema such as CHECK constraints, DEFAULT clauses,
> generated columns, expression indexes, and/or partial indexes. This
> setting can also be controlled using the
> sqlite3_db_config(db,SQLITE_DBCONFIG_TRUSTED_SCHEMA,...) C-language
> interface.
>
> In order to maintain backwards compatibility, this setting is ON by
> default. There are advantages to turning it off, and most applications
> will be unaffected if it is turned off. For that reason, all
> applications are encouraged to switch this setting off on every
> database connection as soon as that connection is opened.
>
> The -DSQLITE_TRUSTED_SCHEMA=0 compile-time option will cause this
> setting to default to OFF.

It seems that some distributions have started to compile SQLite with this more safe compile-time option.

Your insert should succeed if you run earlier in the connection the PRAGMA command

```
PRAGMA trusted_schema=1
```